# Why isn't my project able to find reference to another project in the same solution

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I already had many projects in my solution including Helper project with namespace CompanyName.ProjectName.Helper

I had created a new project and with namespace CompanyName.ProjectName.Data.ModuleName

When I added reference of Data to Helper , it shows the following error:

> The type of namespace name 'Data' does not exists in the namespace CompanyName.ProjectName.Data (are you missing an assembly reference?)

I already added the reference, cleaned solution and rebuild solution, but still getting the same error.

Data project is compiling and has no error when build seperately

Comment: The error refers to something called `Data` in a namespace called `Data`. Is that really what you have in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the TargetFramework of existing project ( CompanyName.ProjectName.Helper ) from .Net 4.0 to .Net 4.5
which is similar to my new project ( CompanyName.ProjectName.Data ) 
This resolved the issue.